# Zoom in Current Window, Restore Previous Size and Position of the Old Window

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to build a simple script that basically:

1. checks whether the active window has changed during a period of time
2. if it has changed
   a. I want the window under the mouse to be resized and moved
   b. restore the position of the last zoomed window (so I can have only one zoomed window at the time)

I wrote this simple script, but I'm missing something, the windows are flashing I don't know why

```ahk
#NoEnv
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

SetTimer, tableDiff, 1000

firstRun := 0
return

tableDiff:
if (firstRun <> 0)
    {
    winUnderMouseLast := winUnderMouseCurrent
    WinGetTitle, titleLast, ahk_id %winUnderMouseLast%
    WinGetClass, classLast, ahk_id %winUnderMouseLast%
    WinGetPos, xLast, yLast, wLast, hLast, ahk_id %winUnderMouseLast%
    }
else
msgbox, 1st run


MouseGetPos,,,winUnderMouseCurrent
WinGetTitle, titleCurrent, ahk_id %winUnderMouseCurrent%
WinGetClass, classCurrent, ahk_id %winUnderMouseCurrent%
WinGetPos, xCurrent, yCurrent, wCurrent, hCurrent, ahk_id %winUnderMouseCurrent%

If (winUnderMouseLast != winUnderMouseCurrent)
 {
    winMove, ahk_id %winUnderMouseLast%,,%xLast%,%yLast%

    ;msgbox, Current %titleCurrent%  Last %titleLast%
    WinMove, ahk_id %winUnderMouseCurrent%,, 421, 156, 1016, 727

 }

firstRun := 1
return
```

Comment: Start by removing `msgbox` and logging everything with `FileAppend, blablabla, logfile.txt` after each line to find what's wrong.

Comment: First of all ty for editing my question, now looks better.   I know I got what is wrong: the script correctly recognize the difference between windows, however I think I'm not storing correctly the vars, namely the previous active window stats. I tried all the afternoon without any luck

Comment: Well indeed, `winUnderMouseLast` has no value at the first run, so the last `if` is true.

Comment: I also tried to change the if condition to (winUnderMouseLast != winUnderMouseCurrent AND winUnderMouseLast != ""), but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WinWaitNotActive](http://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) instead of the timer:

```ahk
loop {
    winwaitnotactive, % "ahk_id " winExist("A")
    mousegetpos,,,id

    if (lastID)
        winmove, ahk_id %lastID%,, x,y,w,h

    wingetpos, x,y,w,h, ahk_id %id%
    winmove, ahk_id %id%,, 421, 156, 1016, 727
    lastID := id
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, ty very much Sir